# Tomcat WebService Deployment Exception

Tags: java, soap, tomcat9, java-13

I get this exception on startup when trying to deploy to server 
Same war file works perfectly fine on my local machine deployment 
Both local and server are using Tomcat 9 and JDK 13

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ClassConstants.<clinit>(ClassConstants.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.createElementsForTypeMappingInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:361)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processClassesAndProperties(AnnotationsProcessor.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.<init>(Generator.java:158)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1131)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextFactory.newContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:188)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.getBindingContextFromSpi(BindingContextFactory.java:207)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:176)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:222)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:195)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:110)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:324)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:100)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:120)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:521)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:300)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:164)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:578)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:303)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:179)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1620)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectCollectionsFactory.getProvider(IndirectCollectionsFactory.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectCollectionsFactory.<clinit>(IndirectCollectionsFactory.java:45)
        ... 56 more
11-Jan-2020 22:20:57.224 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
    javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1620)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
    Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.ExceptionInIni
```

Answer (score 0):

Still haven't figured why it works on my local machine and not any of the deployment servers 
even though I used the same tomcat zip on both instances and both running the JDK 13.

Anyways I Added the this to the pom.xml file and it's working now 
For others experiencing similar issues.

Also Note, eclipselink versions >2.6.8 have compatibility issues with java.persistence.jpa, hence why I'm not using a more recent version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.8</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Not Java 10 compliant -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```